# Can't connect PS3 controller to Pi using Sixaxis

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to use sixaxis to connect a ps3 controller to my Raspberry Pi. When I run `sudo ./sixpair_rpi`, I get:

`Current Bluetooth master: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
 Setting master bd_addr to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`

which does exactly what it is supposed to do; setting the bluetooth dongle and the controller to the right connection. However, when I run sudo `./start_rpi` (I'm using HR-OS1 Framework from GitHub), the controller will wait an eternity and never connect. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?

I am working with a Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian Jessie with an ArbotiX Pro CM-730 Microcontroller. My source code is HR-OS1 Framework from GitHub. My bluetooth dongle is a CSR V4.0.

Comment: did you pull the latest code? try a stable release perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange community.  Do you have robotic hardware (now that's an odd thing to have to ask!) - or are you merely using bits of the code to work a PlayStation 3 controller. Can you add URLs to the micro-controller and to the HR-OS1 framework (is the latter [this](https://github.com/Interbotix/HROS1-Framework) one)? Though it does not explicitly list RPis as a supported platform...

Comment: @SlySven It is unusual that I'm using the controller with a robot. Most of the help I've been looking at online are for games and what-not. Tbh, I'm not really sure what the CM - 730 does (Link [here](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/darwin-op/references/reference/hardware_specifications/electronics/sub_controller_(cm-730).htm)). I'm just following the instructions on the HR-OS1 [Wiki](https://github.com/Interbotix/HROS1-Framework/wiki/ps3_demo) without much beforehand knowledge of Raspbian and Linux.